# how to get a post id using post link in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Am trying to update a record in my database using an `update button` that is linked to a page where the update form is located but each time I click on the button, I get a 404 error (I think maybe the problem is that the page could not read the `id` of the requested post).

This is my **route**

```
Route::get('/pages/update/{id}','CallsController@edit');
Route::post('/pages/update/{id}','CallsController@update');
```

My **CallsController**

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        // $calls = Call::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->where('id', $id)->first();
        // return view('pages.assignCall', compact('calls', 'id'));

        $calls = Call::find($id);
        return view('pages.assignCall')->with('calls', $calls);
    }

public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $calls = new Call();
        $data = $this->validate($request, [
            'call_details'=>'required',
        ]);
        $data['id'] = $id;
        $calls->updateCall($data);

        return redirect('pages.pendingCalls');
    }
```

I also have `update.blade.php` in the `pages` folder inside my views.

This is my **update button**

```
<a href="{{asset('/pages/update')}}>update</a>
```

Comment: put this <a href="{{route('pages.update',$value->id)}}>update</a> instead of your update button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the asset helpers to generate urls, but the [url helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/urls). Also, you have to pass the id of the item you want to update. Because this is missing, you get a 404.

You should do something like this:

```
<a href="{{ url('/pages/update/{$page->id}') }}">update</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use laravel name route. If you use name route then your route should look like this

```
Route::get('/pages/update/{id}','CallsController@edit')->name('pages.update.view');
Route::post('/pages/update/{id}','CallsController@update')->name('pages.update');
```

And your update button should look like this

```
<a href="{{ route('pages.update.view', $call->id) }}">update</a>
```